# Creating x amount of new objects in Class Constructor with for loop and later modifying them in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, object, constructor

I am trying to create x amount of *new Kitten()* in the class constructor *House* and storing them in an object of objects *this.kittens*. But when I later try to modify this object of objects nothing happens or I get undefined. I am however able to modify another property/object of *House*, or more specifically the child class *Playroom* without any problems (*this.exampleKitten*) which was "created normally".

I do understand that the House constructor creates a new kittens object everytime it is called, however I would like for it to behave the same as exampleKitten, that is once it has been created I would like to be able to modify its contents. How can I achieve this? Is it bad practice to create and store x amount of new objects in a constructor the way I do?

I hope you understand my question! Thanks in advance!

```
class House {
  constructor (numberOfKittens) {
    this.numberOfKittens = numberOfKittens
    this.kittens = function () {
         const kitts = {}
          for (let i = 0; i < this.numberOfKittens; i++) {
            kitts[i] = new Kitten(`Kitten ${i}`)
          }
         return kitts
        }
   this.exampleKitten = {7: {name: "Jenny", favoriteToy: "dog"}}
   }

}

class Playroom extends House {
  constructor (numberOfKittens, kittens, exampleKitten) {
    super(numberOfKittens, kittens, exampleKitten)
  }
}

class Kitten {
  constructor (name, favoriteToy) {
    this.name = name
    this.favoriteToy = favoriteToy
    } 
}

let p = new Playroom(15)

p.kittens()[0].name = "Does not work"
p.exampleKitten[7].name = "This does work"
```

Comment: No, the `House` constructor doesn't create any kittens. The `kittens()` function does that, every time it is called. You should indeed move the creation into the constructor to have the code work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply Bergi, but could you please elaborate. Isnt the function already in the constructor?  Or how do you mean?

Comment: The `House.kittens` method creates Kittens and returns them (to the caller, which is outside of the class) but never stores them internally. Besides being bad scoping (a House should not know anything about a Kitten), you should store the result somewhere if you want to re-use them. And `exampleKitten` is a plain object, not an instance of Kitten.

Comment: Thanks Bergi and Sébastien, I get it now...

Comment: @user2768479 The function is created in the constructor, the `kitts` are not. It would have been more appropriate to write `class House {
  constructor (numberOfKittens) {
    this.numberOfKittens = numberOfKittens;
   this.exampleKitten = {…};
   } 
   kittens() { /* a prototype method */  … return kitts; } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be getting a little confused on how/when your kittens get generated vs how you interact with them.

The easier way to set this up is to create a function that will *generate* your kittens. Additionally, add another property that *holds* the kittens.

Given the below setup, once you 'new up' the `Playroom`, it will generate that amount of kittens and set your `kittens` property to the dataset.

You can then interact with the kittens by index by accessing your `kittens` property. ie `Playroom.kittens[<index>].<property>`

```js
class House {
  constructor(numberOfKittens) {
    this.numberOfKittens = numberOfKittens
    this.kittens = this.makeKittens(); // <-- Set a property for your kittens to live
    this.exampleKitten = {
      7: {
        name: "Jenny",
        favoriteToy: "dog"
      }
    }
  }
  makeKittens() { // Make a function that generates your kittens
    const kitts = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < this.numberOfKittens; i++) {
      kitts[i] = new Kitten(`Kitten ${i}`);
    }
    return kitts;
  }
}

class Playroom extends House {
  constructor(numberOfKittens, kittens, exampleKitten) {
    super(numberOfKittens, kittens, exampleKitten)
  }
}

class Kitten {
  constructor(name, favoriteToy) {
    this.name = name
    this.favoriteToy = favoriteToy
  }
}

let p = new Playroom(15)

// p.makeKittens()[0].name = "Does not work"
// p.exampleKitten[7].name = "This does work"

console.log('Kitten Playroom', p);
console.log('First Kitten Name', p.kittens[0].name);
console.log('Updating First Kitten Name to "Frank"');
p.kittens[0].name = 'Frank';
console.log('First Kitten Name', p.kittens[0].name);
```

I would also suggest that updating any `kittens` by index as it's not readible and prone to error (index out of range, being off by one, etc...)

I would suggest adding a function similar to this:

```
updateKitten(idx, name) { // Or whatever you're wanting to update
    const kitten = this.kittens[idx];
    if (kitten) {
        kitten.name = name;
      return kitten;
    }
    throw new Error(`No kitten at index ${idx}`); // or return null or however you want to handle it
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply mwilson, indeed I was confused but this clarifies alot! Big time thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So the `kittens()` method is actually returning an object, but it is not assigning that object as the new value of `kittens`.  What you have there is a factory, and you can use it to create separate instances if you want.

```js
const house = new House()
const kittens1 = house.kittens()
const kittens2 = house.kittens()

kittens1[0] = oldKitten

kittens2[0] = newKitten

kittens1[0] // still oldKitten
```

If you want to manage only one instance at a time on the house object, I would rename your method `addKittens()` or something, and have the result assigned to `this.kittens`.  Furthermore, I would use a native array instead of an object with indexes as keys.  This will allow you to take advantage of all the powerful array methods js has to offer.

```js
class House {

  constructor() {
    this.kittens = []
  }

  addKittens(numOfKittens) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numOfKittens; i++) {
      const newKitten = new Kitten(`Kitten ${i}`)
      this.kittens.push(newKitten)
    }
  }

}
```